# paypal ipn returns html page

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Moving a PayPal to new Hosted Pro Solution breaks IPN: I now receive an HTML page as response, I don't receive VALID or INVALID but only a full html with 
title "Error - Error Processing Payment - PayPal"
The payment is processed, I tested in sandbox, IPN is called but returns this strange html code.

I moved form action to

https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess?

(as indicated in "Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution Integration Guide")

**What is wrong? why IPN returns HTML?**

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify; give the steps you are taking and when you see/get back this weeoe page. IPN does not "return" anything; it is a postback which PayPal makes to your server, so it's not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: IPN is a "handshake": after that PayPal calls my ipn listener, I send back a new POST to PayPal server and it (I called it IPN as an entity but of course is the server which handles this request/response call) "returns" a response with "VALID" or "INVALID", in my case the response is not "VALID" nor "INVALID" but a full html page.

Comment: OK, that answers one question. Was the IPN working before, and if so a) with the same account? and b) which PayPal product are you switching from? Did you change anything in the IPN handler or only in the payment flow?

Comment: ok, I have just found the solution, now I share it if I can help: the address of IPN back request is now different from address to hosted pro paypal buy process.

The address to which point for payment was switched to:
https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess?

BUT IPN back request address was not switched and it is (always):
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?

the documentation lacks in this point, PayPal helpdesk confirmed documentation poorness for this case.

Thanks to everybody.